# Getting error when changing sqlite3 to mysql in windows 2012 server iis

Tags: django

i am trying hosting django application to windows server 2012 iis, everything working fine with sqlite3, but when i changed my database to mysql i am getting error.

raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb.
I changed database settings in django to mysql.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you don't have MySQL module installed in the environment.

Just run > `pip install mysql-python` and try again.